# VUE - Renderizar dinámicamente arrays anidados con v-for

Tags: javascript, array, vue.js

Estoy creando un menú de navegación en VUE por medio de un array padre que contiene cada item que será renderizado mediante un `v-for`.

Cada item puede ser o un simple link o un array con subitems. Si es un array, escribo un nuevo `v-for` para renderizar cada subitem.

El problema viene cuando un subitem es un array, ya que ese array a su vez puede contener dentro otro array más que necesita ser renderizado y desplegado al hacerle click y así sucesivamente.

No es una buena solución escribir un nuevo `v-for` por cada nuevo array, ya que puede que desconozca la cantidad de subarrays que van a existir.

Por lo tanto, necesitaría encontrar la manera de implementar alguna de estas 2 posibles soluciones:

**1.**  Crear dinámicamente cierta cantidad de `v-for`, detectando cuántos subarrays tengo y así poder renderizar el contenido de cada uno.

O si no...

**2.**  Unificar todos los subarrays en un único array y renderizarlos por medio de un solo `v-for`.

Hasta el momento no encuentro la manera de implementar esas posibles soluciones u otra que sea efectiva en este caso.

Este es mi código:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div class="dropDown-list" v-for="point in points" :key="point.key">
      <div :class="{ 'line-list': point.key % 2 === 0 ? true : false }">
        <!-- No list -->
        <div class="dropDown-list-text" @click="pointClick(point)">
          <div
            v-if="point.isList === true && point.open === true"
            class="beak1 beak"
          >
            v
          </div>
          <div
            class="beak2 beak"
            v-if="point.isList === false || point.open === false"
          >
            >
          </div>
          {{ point.name }}
        </div>
        <!-- List -->
        <div v-if="point.isList && point.open">
          <div v-for="subPoint in point.list" :key="subPoint.key">
            <div
              class="dropDown-list-text"
              @click="pointClick(subPoint)"
              style="margin-left: 8px"
            >
              {{ subPoint.name }}
              <div
                v-if="subPoint.isList === true && subPoint.open === true"
                class="dropDown-list-text"
              >
                v
              </div>
              <div
                class="dropDown-list-text"
                v-if="subPoint.isList === false || subPoint.open === false"
              >
                >
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      points: [
        { key: 0, name: "Home", isList: false, link: "/" },
        {
          key: 1,
          name: "Usuarios",
          isList: true,
          open: false,
          list: [
            {
              key: 0,
              name: "User1",
              isList: true,
              open: false,
              list: [
                { key: 0, name: "SubUser1", isList: false, link: "/user2" },
              ],
            },
          ],
        },
        { key: 2, name: "Cerrar sesión", isList: false, link: "/logout" },
      ],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    pointClick(point) {
      if (point.isList) {
        this.points[point.key].open = !this.points[point.key].open;
        // this.$forceUpdate()
      }
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: "Avenir", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
.dropDown-list-text {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.beak {
  display: inline;
  font-size: 30px;
}
.beak1 {
  font-weight: 600;
}
.beak2 {
  font-weight: 700;
}
.line-list {
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  border-top: 2px solid black;
  margin: 20px 0 20px 0;
  padding: 5px;
}
</style>
```

[image: Edit new]

Comment: Puedes crear dos componentes: MenuItem y Menu. Con un `if` puedes comprobar si necesitas un menuitem (un item) o un menu (array de items) e insertar uno u otro recursivamente

Comment: La cuestión no es filtrar si el item es un link o un array. Eso ya se está condicionando mediante los `v-if`. El problema sería cómo renderizar los subarrays anidados que están en cada subitem sin la necesidad de estar escribiendo en el código nuevos `v-for`.

Comment: Por eso hablo de hacerlo recursivo: con un único for recorres la lista y, para cada elemento, creas un componente u otro. Si el componente tiene a su vez hijos, ya se encargará él de mostrarlos

Comment: No termino de entender tu solución. Porque tal y como me la explicas ahora, interpreto que me estás proponiendo lo mismo que ya hace mi código solo que separándolo en componentes. El hecho de separar el código en nuevos componentes no soluciona mi problema. Quizás si hicieras una respuesta incluyendo un ejemplo basado en mi código, podría entender mejor tu solución.

Comment: No conozco Vue lo suficiente para ponerte una respuesta, pero buscando he encontrado justo lo que quería proponer: https://codepen.io/anthonygore/pen/PJKNqa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mi conocimiento de Vue no da como para montarte un ejemplo decente, así que voy a explicar una solución usando puro Javascript:
Las premisas son:

- Un menú es una lista de items
- Cada item puede tener anidado un menú (submenú)

Por tanto, puedes tener un componente que se llama recursivamente si tiene hijos:

```js
//Estructura del menú
const MENU = {
  label: "Elemento con hijos",
  children: [
    { label: "Hijo 1" },
    { label: "Hijo 2 con hijos", children: 
      [
        { label: "Hijo A" },
        { label: "Hijo B", children:
          [
            { label: "Tercer nivel" }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
//simulación del componente:
function generateTree(currentTree, data) {
  // añade el texto del menú
  currentTree += `<div>${data.label}</div>\n`;
  
  //si tiene hijos, los anidamos
  if (data.children) {
    currentTree += "<div>\n" + data.children.reduce(generateTree, '') + '</div>\n';
  }
  return currentTree;
}

const tree = generateTree('', MENU);
document.getElementById('show').innerHTML = tree;
```

```css
div {
  padding-left: 10px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div id ="show"></div>
```

Update: He encontrado un ejemplo funcional con Vue que usa la misma idea y lo he arreglado un poco: https://codepen.io/pawer13/pen/yLzYBGv

Comment: Perfecto, ahora sí. Era justo lo que necesitaba. Pude adaptar tu ejemplo a [mi código](https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-leftpad-g92il?file=/src/App.vue). Muchas gracias.